# journal quality kde plots with seaborn/pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to do some comparative analysis for a publication. I came across seaborn and pandas and really like the ease with which I can create the analysis that I want. However, I find the manuals a bit scanty on the things that I'm trying to understand about the example plots and how to modify the plots to my needs. I'm hoping for some advice here on to get the plots I'm want. Perhaps pandas/seaborn is not what I need.

So, I would like to create subplots, (3,1) or (2,3), of the following figure:

[image: Updated fig using sample data]

Questions:

1. I would like the attached plot to have a title on the colorbar. Not sure if this is possible or exactly what is shown, i.e., is it relative frequency or occurrence or a percentage, etc? How can I put a explanatory tile on the colorbar (oriented vertically).
2. The text is a nice addition. The pearsonr is the correlation, but I'm not sure what is p. My guess is that it is showing the lag, or? If so, how can I remove the p in the text?
3. I would like to make the same kind of figure for different variables and put it all in a subplot.

Here's the code I pieced together from the seaborn manual/examples and from other users here on SO (thanks guys).

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pdb 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats, integrate
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

sns.set(style="white")
sns.set(color_codes=True)

octp = [622.0, 640.0, 616.0, 731.0, 668.0, 631.0, 641.0, 589.0, 801.0,
828.0, 598.0, 742.0,665.0, 611.0, 773.0, 608.0, 734.0, 725.0, 716.0,
699.0, 686.0, 671.0, 700.0, 656.0,686.0, 675.0, 678.0, 653.0, 659.0,
682.0, 674.0, 684.0, 679.0, 704.0, 624.0, 727.0,739.0, 662.0, 801.0, 
633.0, 896.0, 729.0, 659.0, 741.0, 510.0, 836.0, 720.0, 685.0,430.0,
833.0, 710.0, 799.0, 534.0, 532.0, 605.0, 519.0, 850.0, 357.0, 858.0,
497.0,404.0, 456.0, 448.0, 836.0, 462.0, 381.0, 499.0, 673.0, 642.0, 
641.0, 458.0, 809.0,562.0, 742.0, 732.0, 710.0, 658.0, 533.0, 811.0, 
853.0, 856.0, 785.0, 659.0, 697.0,654.0, 673.0, 707.0, 711.0, 423.0, 
751.0, 761.0, 638.0, 576.0, 538.0, 596.0, 718.0,843.0, 640.0, 647.0, 
692.0, 599.0, 607.0, 537.0, 679.0, 712.0, 612.0, 641.0, 665.0,658.0, 
722.0, 656.0, 656.0, 742.0, 505.0, 688.0, 805.0]

cctp = [482.0, 462.0, 425.0, 506.0, 500.0, 464.0, 486.0, 473.0, 577.0,
735.0, 390.0, 590.0,464.0, 417.0, 722.0, 410.0, 679.0, 680.0, 711.0, 
658.0, 687.0, 621.0, 643.0, 690.0,630.0, 661.0, 608.0, 658.0, 624.0,
646.0, 651.0, 634.0, 612.0, 636.0, 607.0, 539.0,706.0, 614.0, 706.0,
401.0, 720.0, 746.0, 511.0, 700.0, 453.0, 677.0, 637.0, 605.0,454.0,
733.0, 535.0, 725.0, 668.0, 513.0, 470.0, 589.0, 765.0, 596.0, 749.0,
462.0,469.0, 514.0, 511.0, 789.0, 647.0, 324.0, 555.0, 670.0, 656.0,
786.0, 374.0, 757.0,645.0, 744.0, 708.0, 497.0, 654.0, 288.0, 705.0,
703.0, 446.0, 675.0, 440.0, 652.0,589.0, 542.0, 661.0, 631.0, 343.0, 
585.0, 632.0, 591.0, 602.0, 365.0, 535.0, 663.0,561.0, 448.0, 582.0, 
591.0, 535.0, 475.0, 422.0, 599.0, 594.0, 569.0, 576.0, 622.0,483.0,
539.0, 515.0, 621.0, 443.0, 435.0, 502.0, 443.0]

cctp = pd.Series(cctp, name='CTP [hPa]')  
octp = pd.Series(octp, name='CTP [hPa]')

formatter = tkr.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_scientific(True)
formatter.set_powerlimits((-2, 2))

g = sns.jointplot(cctp,octp, kind="kde",size=8,space=0.2,cbar=True,
                  n_levels=50,cbar_kws={"format": formatter})
# add a line x=y
x0, x1 = g.ax_joint.get_xlim()
y0, y1 = g.ax_joint.get_ylim()
lims = [max(x0, y0), min(x1, y1)]
g.ax_joint.plot(lims, lims, ':k')

plt.show()

plt.savefig('test_fig.png')
```

I know I'm asking a lot here. So I put the questions in order of priority.

Comment: Can you make your code a [MCVE]? For example, try using some random data instead of using a data file. We also don't know what modules you have imported (e.g. what is `nc`)? That should help you get a good answer

Comment: Will do. The sample data will take a few minutes.

Comment: @tom Appreciate the cleaning up of the post and request for clarification and sample data. I've now added some sample data that should meet the requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: To set the colorbar label, you can add the `label` key to the `cbar_kws` dict:

```
 cbar_kws={"format": formatter, "label": 'My colorbar'}
```

2: To change the stats label, you need to first slightly modify the `stats.pearsonr` function to only return the first value, instead of the `(pearsonr, p)` tuple:

```
pr = lambda a, b: stats.pearsonr(a, b)[0]
```

Then, you can change that function using `jointplot`'s `stat_func` kwarg:

```
stat_func=pr
```

and finally, you need to change the annotation to get the label right:

```
annot_kws={'stat':'pearsonr'})
```

Putting that all together:

```
pr = lambda a, b: stats.pearsonr(a, b)[0]

g = sns.jointplot(cctp,octp, kind="kde",size=8,space=0.2,cbar=True,
        n_levels=50,cbar_kws={"format": formatter, "label": 'My colorbar'},
        stat_func=pr, annot_kws={'stat':'pearsonr'})
```

3: I don't think its possible to put everything in a `subplot` with `jointplot`.  Happy to be proven wrong there though.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! This is a very good answer. I'm interesting also in how you figured it out. Is there a more detailed manual? I can find out how to merge each unique fig in latex.

Comment: the `cbar` label I just guessed – although I originally found a way to do it by finding the matplotlib axis, and setting the label on that (`g.fig.axes[-1].set_ylabel()`). The `stat_func` I figured out from the [`JointGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid) and [`jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot) manual pages

Comment: Ok. Good guess. I see now the stat_func on the JointGrid page. I had missed that, as my focus was on the Jointplot. Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @tmdavison So, what's the exact meaning of the colorbar?